# A simple script that works for hover, but why can't I get it to work for clicks?

Tags: jquery

I have a very simple js script that works for hovers, but I want to convert the hover into a click feature. When I try to switch hover to click though, it does not work.

Here is the complete example script just for reference. When someone hovers over this class, a little text with a background appears below.
http://pastebin.com/JMTfvDAa

Here's what I tried for click
http://pastebin.com/M0X37APD

If someone could help me covert the hover into click, I would heavily appreciate it!

Thanks,

Comment: I can't recommend http://jsfiddle.net strongly enough as a way to post code samples on SO.

Comment: Check out http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: It should work. I guess, you have error somewhere else. Can you use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) instead of pastebin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like below,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menu a").click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if (!$this.hasClass('clicked')) {
            $this.next("em").animate({
                opacity: "show",
                bottom: "-155"
            }, "fast");

            $this.addClass('clicked');
        } else {
            $this.next("em").animate({
                opacity: "hide",
                bottom: "-165"
            }, "fast");

            $this.removeClass('clicked');
        }

    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/6DYsS/1/)

Comment: Ah this is fantastic thank you so much! Sorry about that I will use jsfiddle next time thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to toggle the state of an element with a click, you'll need to store its state somewhere else -- either a global variable (not a good habit) or in a `.data()` variable in the element itself.

Example:

```
$(".menu a").bind('click', function () {
    $el = $(this).next('em');
    if ($el.data('switched')) {
        $el.data('switched',false)
           .animate({
            opacity: 1,
            bottom: "-155"
        }, "fast");
    } else {
        $el.data('switched',true)
           .animate({
            opacity: 0,
            bottom: "-165"
        }, "fast");
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".menu a").toggle(function() {
                 $(this).next("em").animate({opacity: "show", bottom: "-155"}, "fast");
            }, function() {
                 $(this).next("em").animate({opacity: "hide", bottom: "-165"}, "fast");
            }); 
        });
```

Jquery has a built in function for that.